# Conky on ubuntu 15.10 shows window decoration

Tags: 15.10, conky

After updating to ubuntu 15.10 conky show window borders and shadows.

[image]

Any way I can get around it?

Here is then content of the theme:

```
#==============================================================================
#                               conkyrc_seamod
# Date    : 05/02/2012
# Author  : SeaJey
# Version : v0.1
# License : Distributed under the terms of GNU GPL version 2 or later
# 
# This version is a modification of conkyrc_lunatico wich is modification of conkyrc_orange
# 
# conkyrc_orange:    http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php?content=137503&forumpage=0
# conkyrc_lunatico:  http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php?content=142884
#==============================================================================

background yes
update_interval 1

cpu_avg_samples 1
net_avg_samples 2
temperature_unit celsius

double_buffer yes
no_buffers yes
text_buffer_size 2048

gap_x 40
gap_y 70
minimum_size 300 900
maximum_width 350

own_window yes
own_window_type normal
own_window_class conky
own_window_transparent no
own_window_argb_visual yes
own_window_colour 000000
own_window_argb_value 102
own_window_hints undecorate,sticky,skip_taskbar,skip_pager,below

border_inner_margin 0
border_outer_margin 0
alignment top_right


draw_shades no
draw_outline no
draw_borders no
draw_graph_borders no

override_utf8_locale yes
use_xft yes
xftfont caviar dreams:size=10
xftalpha 0.5
uppercase no

# Defining colors
default_color FFFFFF
# Shades of Gray
color1 DDDDDD
color2 AAAAAA
color3 888888
# Orange
color4 EF5A29
# Green
color5 77B753

# Loading lua script for drawning rings
lua_load ./seamod_rings.lua
lua_draw_hook_post main

## System information using conky capabilities

# Header with base system info
own_window_argb_value 102
own_window_colour 000000
TEXT
${font Ubuntu:size=10,weight:bold}${color4}SYSTEM ${hr 2}
${offset 15}${font Ubuntu:size=10,weight:normal}${color1}$sysname $kernel
${offset 15}${font Ubuntu:size=10,weight:normal}${color1}$nodename
${offset 15}${font Ubuntu:size=10,weight:normal}${color1}Uptime: $uptime

# Showing CPU Graph
${voffset 20}
${offset 120}${cpugraph 40,183 666666 666666}${voffset -25}
${offset 90}${font Ubuntu:size=10,weight:bold}${color5}CPU
# Showing TOP 5 CPU-consumers
${offset 105}${font Ubuntu:size=10,weight:normal}${color4}${top name 1}${alignr}${top cpu 1}%
${offset 105}${font Ubuntu:size=10,weight:normal}${color1}${top name 2}${alignr}${top cpu 2}%
${offset 105}${font Ubuntu:size=10,weight:normal}${color2}${top name 3}${alignr}${top cpu 3}%
${offset 105}${font Ubuntu:size=10,weight:normal}${color3}${top name 4}${alignr}${top cpu 4}%
${offset 105}${font Ubuntu:size=10,weight:normal}${color3}${top name 5}${alignr}${top cpu 5}%

#Showing memory part with TOP 5
${voffset 40}
${offset 90}${font Ubuntu:size=10,weight:bold}${color5}MEM
${offset 105}${font Ubuntu:size=10,weight:normal}${color4}${top_mem name 1}${alignr}${top_mem mem 1}%
${offset 105}${font Ubuntu:size=10,weight:normal}${color1}${top_mem name 2}${alignr}${top_mem mem 2}%
${offset 105}${font Ubuntu:size=10,weight:normal}${color2}${top_mem name 3}${alignr}${top_mem mem 3}%
${offset 105}${font Ubuntu:size=10,weight:normal}${color3}${top_mem name 4}${alignr}${top_mem mem 4}%
${offset 105}${font Ubuntu:size=10,weight:normal}${color3}${top_mem name 4}${alignr}${top_mem mem 5}%

# Showing disk partitions: root, home and Data
${voffset 28}
${offset 90}${font Ubuntu:size=10,weight:bold}${color5}DISKS
${offset 120}${diskiograph 33,183 666666 666666}${voffset -30}
${voffset 20}
${offset 15}${font Ubuntu:size=9,weight:bold}${color1}Free: ${font Ubuntu:size=9,weight:normal}${fs_free /}${alignr}${font Ubuntu:size=9,weight:bold}Used: ${font Ubuntu:size=9,weight:normal}${fs_used /}
${offset 15}${font Ubuntu:size=9,weight:bold}${color1}Free: ${font Ubuntu:size=9,weight:normal}${fs_free /home}${alignr}${font Ubuntu:size=9,weight:bold}Used: ${font Ubuntu:size=9,weight:normal}${fs_used /home}
${offset 15}${font Ubuntu:size=9,weight:bold}${color1}Free: ${font Ubuntu:size=9,weight:normal}${fs_free /media/Data}${alignr}${font Ubuntu:size=9,weight:bold}Used: ${font Ubuntu:size=9,weight:normal}${fs_used /media/Data}

# Network data (my desktop have only LAN). ETHERNET ring is mostly useless but looks pretty, main info is in the graphs
${voffset 43}
${offset 90}${font Ubuntu:size=10,weight:bold}${color5}ETHERNET
${voffset 40}             
${offset 15}${color1}${font Ubuntu:size=9,weight:bold}Up: ${alignr}${font Ubuntu:size=9,weight:normal}$color2${upspeed eth0} / ${totalup}
${offset 15}${upspeedgraph eth0 40,285 4B1B0C FF5C2B 100 -l}
${offset 15}${color1}${font Ubuntu:size=9,weight:bold}Down: ${alignr}${font Ubuntu:size=9,weight:normal}$color2${downspeed eth0} / ${totaldown}
${offset 15}${downspeedgraph eth0 40,285 324D23 77B753 100 -l}

${color4}${hr 2}
```

Here is the content of seamod_rings.lua:

```
--==============================================================================
--                            seamod_rings.lua
--
--  Date    : 05/02/2012
--  Author  : SeaJey
--  Version : v0.1
--  License : Distributed under the terms of GNU GPL version 2 or later
--
--  This version is a modification of lunatico_rings.lua wich is modification of conky_orange.lua 
--
--  conky_orange.lua:    http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php?content=137503&forumpage=0
--  lunatico_rings.lua:  http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php?content=142884
--==============================================================================

require 'cairo'


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--                                                                    gauge DATA
gauge = {
{
    name='cpu',                    arg='cpu0',                  max_value=100,
    x=70,                          y=130,
    graph_radius=54,
    graph_thickness=5,
    graph_start_angle=180,
    graph_unit_angle=2.7,          graph_unit_thickness=2.7,
    graph_bg_colour=0xffffff,      graph_bg_alpha=0.1,
    graph_fg_colour=0xFFFFFF,      graph_fg_alpha=0.3,
    hand_fg_colour=0xEF5A29,       hand_fg_alpha=1.0,
    txt_radius=64,
    txt_weight=0,                  txt_size=9.0,
    txt_fg_colour=0xEF5A29,        txt_fg_alpha=1.0,
    graduation_radius=28,
    graduation_thickness=0,        graduation_mark_thickness=1,
    graduation_unit_angle=27,
    graduation_fg_colour=0xFFFFFF, graduation_fg_alpha=0.3,
    caption='',
    caption_weight=1,              caption_size=9.0,
    caption_fg_colour=0xFFFFFF,    caption_fg_alpha=0.3,
},
{
    name='cpu',                    arg='cpu1',                  max_value=100,
    x=70,                          y=130,
    graph_radius=48,
    graph_thickness=5,
    graph_start_angle=180,
    graph_unit_angle=2.7,          graph_unit_thickness=2.7,
    graph_bg_colour=0xffffff,      graph_bg_alpha=0.1,
    graph_fg_colour=0xFFFFFF,      graph_fg_alpha=0.3,
    hand_fg_colour=0xEF5A29,       hand_fg_alpha=1.0,
    txt_radius=40,
    txt_weight=0,                  txt_size=9.0,
    txt_fg_colour=0xEF5A29,        txt_fg_alpha=1.0,
    graduation_radius=28,
    graduation_thickness=0,        graduation_mark_thickness=1,
    graduation_unit_angle=27,
    graduation_fg_colour=0xFFFFFF, graduation_fg_alpha=0.3,
    caption='',
    caption_weight=1,              caption_size=9.0,
    caption_fg_colour=0xFFFFFF,    caption_fg_alpha=0.3,
},
{
    name='cpu',                    arg='cpu2',                  max_value=100,
    x=70,                          y=130,
    graph_radius=20,
    graph_thickness=5,
    graph_start_angle=180,
    graph_unit_angle=2.7,          graph_unit_thickness=2.7,
    graph_bg_colour=0xffffff,      graph_bg_alpha=0.1,
    graph_fg_colour=0xFFFFFF,      graph_fg_alpha=0.3,
    hand_fg_colour=0xEF5A29,       hand_fg_alpha=1.0,
    txt_radius=30,
    txt_weight=0,                  txt_size=9.0,
    txt_fg_colour=0xEF5A29,        txt_fg_alpha=1.0,
    graduation_radius=28,
    graduation_thickness=0,        graduation_mark_thickness=1,
    graduation_unit_angle=27,
    graduation_fg_colour=0xFFFFFF, graduation_fg_alpha=0.3,
    caption='',
    caption_weight=1,              caption_size=9.0,
    caption_fg_colour=0xFFFFFF,    caption_fg_alpha=0.3,
},
{
    name='cpu',                    arg='cpu3',                  max_value=100,
    x=70,                          y=130,
    graph_radius=14,
    graph_thickness=5,
    graph_start_angle=180,
    graph_unit_angle=2.7,          graph_unit_thickness=2.7,
    graph_bg_colour=0xffffff,      graph_bg_alpha=0.1,
    graph_fg_colour=0xFFFFFF,      graph_fg_alpha=0.3,
    hand_fg_colour=0xEF5A29,       hand_fg_alpha=1.0,
    txt_radius=4,
    txt_weight=0,                  txt_size=9.0,
    txt_fg_colour=0xEF5A29,        txt_fg_alpha=1.0,
    graduation_radius=28,
    graduation_thickness=0,        graduation_mark_thickness=1,
    graduation_unit_angle=27,
    graduation_fg_colour=0xFFFFFF, graduation_fg_alpha=0.3,
    caption='',
    caption_weight=1,              caption_size=9.0,
    caption_fg_colour=0xFFFFFF,    caption_fg_alpha=0.3,
},
{
    name='memperc',                arg='',                      max_value=100,
    x=70,                          y=300,
    graph_radius=54,
    graph_thickness=10,
    graph_start_angle=180,
    graph_unit_angle=2.7,          graph_unit_thickness=2.7,
    graph_bg_colour=0xffffff,      graph_bg_alpha=0.1,
    graph_fg_colour=0xFFFFFF,      graph_fg_alpha=0.3,
    hand_fg_colour=0xEF5A29,       hand_fg_alpha=1.0,
    txt_radius=42,
    txt_weight=0,                  txt_size=9.0,
    txt_fg_colour=0xEF5A29,        txt_fg_alpha=1.0,
    graduation_radius=23,
    graduation_thickness=0,        graduation_mark_thickness=2,
    graduation_unit_angle=27,
    graduation_fg_colour=0xFFFFFF, graduation_fg_alpha=0.5,
    caption='',
    caption_weight=1,              caption_size=10.0,
    caption_fg_colour=0xFFFFFF,    caption_fg_alpha=0.3,
},
{
    name='fs_used_perc',           arg='/media/Data',                     max_value=100,
    x=70,                          y=470,
    graph_radius=54,
    graph_thickness=7,
    graph_start_angle=180,
    graph_unit_angle=2.7,          graph_unit_thickness=2.7,
    graph_bg_colour=0xffffff,      graph_bg_alpha=0.1,
    graph_fg_colour=0xFFFFFF,      graph_fg_alpha=0.3,
    hand_fg_colour=0xEF5A29,       hand_fg_alpha=1.0,
    txt_radius=64,
    txt_weight=0,                  txt_size=9.0,
    txt_fg_colour=0xEF5A29,        txt_fg_alpha=1.0,
    graduation_radius=23,
    graduation_thickness=0,        graduation_mark_thickness=2,
    graduation_unit_angle=27,
    graduation_fg_colour=0xFFFFFF, graduation_fg_alpha=0.3,
    caption='Data',
    caption_weight=1,              caption_size=12.0,
    caption_fg_colour=0xFFFFFF,    caption_fg_alpha=0.5,
},
{
    name='fs_used_perc',           arg='/home/',                     max_value=100,
    x=70,                          y=470,
    graph_radius=42,
    graph_thickness=7,
    graph_start_angle=180,
    graph_unit_angle=2.7,          graph_unit_thickness=2.7,
    graph_bg_colour=0xffffff,      graph_bg_alpha=0.1,
    graph_fg_colour=0xFFFFFF,      graph_fg_alpha=0.3,
    hand_fg_colour=0xEF5A29,       hand_fg_alpha=1.0,
    txt_radius=32,
    txt_weight=0,                  txt_size=9.0,
    txt_fg_colour=0xEF5A29,        txt_fg_alpha=1.0,
    graduation_radius=23,
    graduation_thickness=0,        graduation_mark_thickness=2,
    graduation_unit_angle=27,
    graduation_fg_colour=0xFFFFFF, graduation_fg_alpha=0.3,
    caption='Home',
    caption_weight=1,              caption_size=12.0,
    caption_fg_colour=0xFFFFFF,    caption_fg_alpha=0.5,
},
{
    name='fs_used_perc',           arg='/',                     max_value=100,
    x=70,                          y=470,
    graph_radius=30,
    graph_thickness=7,
    graph_start_angle=180,
    graph_unit_angle=2.7,          graph_unit_thickness=2.7,
    graph_bg_colour=0xffffff,      graph_bg_alpha=0.1,
    graph_fg_colour=0xFFFFFF,      graph_fg_alpha=0.3,
    hand_fg_colour=0xEF5A29,       hand_fg_alpha=1.0,
    txt_radius=22,
    txt_weight=0,                  txt_size=9.0,
    txt_fg_colour=0xEF5A29,        txt_fg_alpha=1.0,
    graduation_radius=23,
    graduation_thickness=0,        graduation_mark_thickness=2,
    graduation_unit_angle=27,
    graduation_fg_colour=0xFFFFFF, graduation_fg_alpha=0.3,
    caption='Root',
    caption_weight=1,              caption_size=12.0,
    caption_fg_colour=0xFFFFFF,    caption_fg_alpha=0.5,
},
{
    name='downspeedf',           arg='eth0',                     max_value=100,
    x=70,                          y=660,
    graph_radius=54,
    graph_thickness=7,
    graph_start_angle=180,
    graph_unit_angle=2.7,          graph_unit_thickness=2.7,
    graph_bg_colour=0xffffff,      graph_bg_alpha=0.1,
    graph_fg_colour=0xFFFFFF,      graph_fg_alpha=0.3,
    hand_fg_colour=0xEF5A29,       hand_fg_alpha=0,
    txt_radius=64,
    txt_weight=0,                  txt_size=9.0,
    txt_fg_colour=0xEF5A29,        txt_fg_alpha=1.0,
    graduation_radius=28,
    graduation_thickness=0,        graduation_mark_thickness=1,
    graduation_unit_angle=27,
    graduation_fg_colour=0xFFFFFF, graduation_fg_alpha=0.3,
    caption='Down',
    caption_weight=1,              caption_size=12.0,
    caption_fg_colour=0xFFFFFF,    caption_fg_alpha=0.5,
},
{
    name='upspeedf',           arg='eth0',                     max_value=100,
    x=70,                          y=660,
    graph_radius=42,
    graph_thickness=7,
    graph_start_angle=180,
    graph_unit_angle=2.7,          graph_unit_thickness=2.7,
    graph_bg_colour=0xffffff,      graph_bg_alpha=0.1,
    graph_fg_colour=0xFFFFFF,      graph_fg_alpha=0.3,
    hand_fg_colour=0xEF5A29,       hand_fg_alpha=0,
    txt_radius=30,
    txt_weight=0,                  txt_size=9.0,
    txt_fg_colour=0xEF5A29,        txt_fg_alpha=1.0,
    graduation_radius=28,
    graduation_thickness=0,        graduation_mark_thickness=1,
    graduation_unit_angle=27,
    graduation_fg_colour=0xFFFFFF, graduation_fg_alpha=0.3,
    caption='Up',
    caption_weight=1,              caption_size=12.0,
    caption_fg_colour=0xFFFFFF,    caption_fg_alpha=0.5,
},
}

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--                                                                 rgb_to_r_g_b
-- converts color in hexa to decimal
--
function rgb_to_r_g_b(colour, alpha)
    return ((colour / 0x10000) % 0x100) / 255., ((colour / 0x100) % 0x100) / 255., (colour % 0x100) / 255., alpha
end

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--                                                            angle_to_position
-- convert degree to rad and rotate (0 degree is top/north)
--
function angle_to_position(start_angle, current_angle)
    local pos = current_angle + start_angle
    return ( ( pos * (2 * math.pi / 360) ) - (math.pi / 2) )
end


-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--                                                              draw_gauge_ring
-- displays gauges
--
function draw_gauge_ring(display, data, value)
    local max_value = data['max_value']
    local x, y = data['x'], data['y']
    local graph_radius = data['graph_radius']
    local graph_thickness, graph_unit_thickness = data['graph_thickness'], data['graph_unit_thickness']
    local graph_start_angle = data['graph_start_angle']
    local graph_unit_angle = data['graph_unit_angle']
    local graph_bg_colour, graph_bg_alpha = data['graph_bg_colour'], data['graph_bg_alpha']
    local graph_fg_colour, graph_fg_alpha = data['graph_fg_colour'], data['graph_fg_alpha']
    local hand_fg_colour, hand_fg_alpha = data['hand_fg_colour'], data['hand_fg_alpha']
    local graph_end_angle = (max_value * graph_unit_angle) % 360

    -- background ring
    cairo_arc(display, x, y, graph_radius, angle_to_position(graph_start_angle, 0), angle_to_position(graph_start_angle, graph_end_angle))
    cairo_set_source_rgba(display, rgb_to_r_g_b(graph_bg_colour, graph_bg_alpha))
    cairo_set_line_width(display, graph_thickness)
    cairo_stroke(display)

    -- arc of value
    local val = value % (max_value + 1)
    local start_arc = 0
    local stop_arc = 0
    local i = 1
    while i <= val do
        start_arc = (graph_unit_angle * i) - graph_unit_thickness
        stop_arc = (graph_unit_angle * i)
        cairo_arc(display, x, y, graph_radius, angle_to_position(graph_start_angle, start_arc), angle_to_position(graph_start_angle, stop_arc))
        cairo_set_source_rgba(display, rgb_to_r_g_b(graph_fg_colour, graph_fg_alpha))
        cairo_stroke(display)
        i = i + 1
    end
    local angle = start_arc

    -- hand
    start_arc = (graph_unit_angle * val) - (graph_unit_thickness * 2)
    stop_arc = (graph_unit_angle * val)
    cairo_arc(display, x, y, graph_radius, angle_to_position(graph_start_angle, start_arc), angle_to_position(graph_start_angle, stop_arc))
    cairo_set_source_rgba(display, rgb_to_r_g_b(hand_fg_colour, hand_fg_alpha))
    cairo_stroke(display)

    -- graduations marks
    local graduation_radius = data['graduation_radius']
    local graduation_thickness, graduation_mark_thickness = data['graduation_thickness'], data['graduation_mark_thickness']
    local graduation_unit_angle = data['graduation_unit_angle']
    local graduation_fg_colour, graduation_fg_alpha = data['graduation_fg_colour'], data['graduation_fg_alpha']
    if graduation_radius > 0 and graduation_thickness > 0 and graduation_unit_angle > 0 then
        local nb_graduation = graph_end_angle / graduation_unit_angle
        local i = 0
        while i < nb_graduation do
            cairo_set_line_width(display, graduation_thickness)
            start_arc = (graduation_unit_angle * i) - (graduation_mark_thickness / 2)
            stop_arc = (graduation_unit_angle * i) + (graduation_mark_thickness / 2)
            cairo_arc(display, x, y, graduation_radius, angle_to_position(graph_start_angle, start_arc), angle_to_position(graph_start_angle, stop_arc))
            cairo_set_source_rgba(display,rgb_to_r_g_b(graduation_fg_colour,graduation_fg_alpha))
            cairo_stroke(display)
            cairo_set_line_width(display, graph_thickness)
            i = i + 1
        end
    end

    -- text
    local txt_radius = data['txt_radius']
    local txt_weight, txt_size = data['txt_weight'], data['txt_size']
    local txt_fg_colour, txt_fg_alpha = data['txt_fg_colour'], data['txt_fg_alpha']
    local movex = txt_radius * math.cos(angle_to_position(graph_start_angle, angle))
    local movey = txt_radius * math.sin(angle_to_position(graph_start_angle, angle))
    cairo_select_font_face (display, "ubuntu", CAIRO_FONT_SLANT_NORMAL, txt_weight)
    cairo_set_font_size (display, txt_size)
    cairo_set_source_rgba (display, rgb_to_r_g_b(txt_fg_colour, txt_fg_alpha))
    cairo_move_to (display, x + movex - (txt_size / 2), y + movey + 3)
    cairo_show_text (display, value)
    cairo_stroke (display)

    -- caption
    local caption = data['caption']
    local caption_weight, caption_size = data['caption_weight'], data['caption_size']
    local caption_fg_colour, caption_fg_alpha = data['caption_fg_colour'], data['caption_fg_alpha']
    local tox = graph_radius * (math.cos((graph_start_angle * 2 * math.pi / 360)-(math.pi/2)))
    local toy = graph_radius * (math.sin((graph_start_angle * 2 * math.pi / 360)-(math.pi/2)))
    cairo_select_font_face (display, "ubuntu", CAIRO_FONT_SLANT_NORMAL, caption_weight);
    cairo_set_font_size (display, caption_size)
    cairo_set_source_rgba (display, rgb_to_r_g_b(caption_fg_colour, caption_fg_alpha))
    cairo_move_to (display, x + tox + 5, y + toy + 1)
    -- bad hack but not enough time !
    if graph_start_angle < 105 then
        cairo_move_to (display, x + tox - 30, y + toy + 1)
    end
    cairo_show_text (display, caption)
    cairo_stroke (display)
end


-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--                                                               go_gauge_rings
-- loads data and displays gauges
--
function go_gauge_rings(display)
    local function load_gauge_rings(display, data)
        local str, value = '', 0
        str = string.format('${%s %s}',data['name'], data['arg'])
        str = conky_parse(str)
        value = tonumber(str)
        draw_gauge_ring(display, data, value)
    end

    for i in pairs(gauge) do
        load_gauge_rings(display, gauge[i])
    end
end

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--                                                                         MAIN
function conky_main()
    if conky_window == nil then 
        return
    end

    local cs = cairo_xlib_surface_create(conky_window.display, conky_window.drawable, conky_window.visual, conky_window.width, conky_window.height)
    local display = cairo_create(cs)

    local updates = conky_parse('${updates}')
    update_num = tonumber(updates)

    if update_num > 5 then
        go_gauge_rings(display)
    end

    cairo_surface_destroy(cs)
    cairo_destroy(display)

end
```

The other two problems with it, is that it appears in the docker as an icon and it also stays only on one screen.

Comment: I assume that is a conky_seamod theme. Can you provide the content of the file?

Comment: Adjust the line `own_window_hints undecorated,sticky,skip_taskbar,skip_pager,below` . What do you mean by shadow? BTW can you provide seamod_rings.lua file? Thanks

Comment: The line adjustment did the trick thank you, can you pun that in an answer so I can be mark it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had a similar problem after upgrading to Ubuntu 15.10.
You can adjust the line:

```
own_window_hints undecorated,sticky,skip_taskbar,skip_pager,below
```

in `~/.conky/Conky Seamod/conky_seamod` file.
After that the conky functioned as default.

If this solves the problem, you can accept the answer so others can learn from it.

Comment: I upgraded from 15.04 to 16.04 and this did not help, but setting the own_window_type  from normal to desktop, did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just install conky-manager .
In terminal :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:teejee2008/ppa

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install conky-manager
```

Open conky-manager  ,select the theme, go to **edit** **widget>transparency** ,although it is set to transparent, play a little with setting it to opaque and then back to transparent.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/712768/686435) solution suggested by [VRR](https://askubuntu.com/users/364243/vrr)

you can replace all 'undecorate' founded inside your conky folder by 'undecorated'.

go to the conky folder `~/.conky`

then execute

```
find ./ -type f -exec sed -i "s/undecorate/undecorated/g" {} \; 
find ./ -type f -exec sed -i "s/undecoratedd/undecorated/g" {} \;
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer, I have not used ubuntu for a wile now, if someone else can test this I will mark at answer